The 'footer-widgets' class doesnt seem to appear in my standard Genesis Wordpress theme
I'm using the standard Genesis Wordpress theme. My website spo-design.nl does not have the widgets appearing. The class itself 'footer-widgets' does not appear in the css at all. I've tried the command add_theme_support in functions PhP but that does not work either. I've disabled all plugins and used another theme but yet there the class doesnt show up either. I've read all threads and yet no answer. Does anyone know what else I can do. To me this is one of the most annoying things about wordpress. it always takes some time till u find some weird problem that just takes days and days before it's gone. :( bugs XD
